# Unable to connect to mysql on digitalocean using workbench over ssh

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, laravel-5.3, digital-ocean

I have got my droplet set with the laravel app and database. Created my db while on putty ssh. Now when I am trying to connect to my mysql database as in image, i am getting error.

[image]

Error: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, plese refer to logs for details.

Note that my credentials are right, as that what I use to connect through putty. Any help on how can I see view my database?

Answer (score 6):

Got this solved like this.

Turns out this is an ssh level issue. The digital ocean server doesn't have the support for the Kex algorithm as mentioned in the error the following can be done to fix this.

Following steps needs to be done on the digital ocean server itself

1- Add the following lines to this file **on the digital ocean server**

> $ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

2- Restart the ssh service on the server

> $ sudo service ssh restart

Now try connecting with mysql workbench again you should see that error gone. Check the logs for more errors if not successful but this did the trick for me.

Comment: Worked for a mac machine against AWS EC2 server also. thanks.

Comment: Also worked from OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan) connecting to MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. Note that I didn't have the problem on my Mac laptop, which runs OS X Sierra. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue on High Sierra using workbench 6.17 I just downloaded a newer version of workbench 8.0.12 and it fixed the issue straight away. You can find older versions of workbench here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/