# Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager - Connecting to digital ocean ubuntu server using Mysql Workbench over SSH

Tags: ssh, mysql-workbench, digital-ocean, devops

Got myself a new ubuntu 14.04 server with LAMP installed on digital ocean.

Filled in the Workbench details as required for connecting over ssh

[image]

But I kept on getting this when hitting the test connection button.

**Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details**

After verifying the work bench logs at location

> $ tail -200f /home/user/.mysql/workbench/log/wb.log

The problem showed up like this : **SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)**

[image]

Comment: You passed the wrong key file. You're supposed to pass the path to the private key (usually `id_rsa`). You passed the path to your public key. `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: doesn't work with any of the key files. this is how I solved it http://stackoverflow.com/a/43103762/3429655 and it works with id_rsa.pub as well

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by adding KexAlgorithms on sshd_config and restart ssh service.

> KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Comment: KexAlgorithms, or KeyAlgorithms?

Comment: KexAlgorithms. :)

Answer (score -1):

I solved the topic problem "Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager" by removing ~/.ssh/known_hosts and let the system create it again.

```
mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts.backup
```